# Why matlab plot uses soo much memory?

Tags: matlab, memory, plot

When I plot even the simplest plot in Matlab, each plot takes about 400MB of memory.
I've tried un-and-re-installing, with no effect.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

I've tried other pc's in our office and found the simplest plot takes about 20MB of memory, that seems a lot, but it's sane.

0.4GB however is insane and plotting more than three plots renders my computer useless.

I've tried:

```
 plot(1:10,1:10);
```

or

```
 plot(1,1);
```

and similar plot-commands.

`figure();` itself does not use that much of memory, only plots.

Specs: R2015a, Windows 7 Pro SP1, Dell, i5

Comment: How do you measure memory taken by a plot?

Comment: This issue sounds like it might be better addressed in the [MathWorks forms](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) or by filing a [service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs). This could possibly be a graphics card or Java issue. FYI, R2015a on OS X 10.10.3 takes about 2–10 MB per figure with `plot(1:10,1:10)`.

Comment: i used task manager to messure memory usage. it pops up 400MB every plot i open, and back down for each plot i close.

Comment: i also tried installing latest java  software with no results. i will probably end up formatting my pc, and if that doesn't work, changing it should.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Running MATLAB R2013a on Mac OSX 10.10.3 and it fluctuates between 4 - 10 MB.  Suggest you contact MathWorks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted Mathworks support and they recommended typing in matlab (once):

```
opengl('save','software')
```

then restarting matlab.

This configures graphics NOT to use hardware openGL support.

This solved my problem !!